bone rotates in the opposite direction in godot
First time Godot user here. Using version 4.2.1 mono. I am trying to animate the sprites with AnimationPlayer
The default rotation for the node (Bone2D) is -170.8, so on the next frame I rotate it by -33 degrees and instead of going further on the negative side - it instead ends up on 155.3 (e.g. positive value).
This causes the animated sprite to go the opposite direction on the interpolated frames. Is there a way around this problem in Godot 4? For example, allowing rotation lower than -179.99 degrees?

Green - expected rotation. Red - actual.

